# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'cantidad' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

una disculpa pero tengo un problema con ese error que no me permite cambiar propiedades especificas de un objeto.
Estoy trabajando en un pequeño proyecto de react con JS y Typescript en el que trato de incluir una librería para un elemento tipo excel en react llamada reactgrid de silevis. Cuando trato de hacer un cambio en la información escrita en la tabla de excel, la aplicación colapsa y me muestra el error de *Cannot assign to read only property...* etc. Este es el código que intenta hacer el cambio en el objeto

```
const applyChangesToObjects = (
    changes: CellChange[],
    prevObjects: ObjOrdAdm[]
  ): ObjOrdAdm[] => {
    changes.forEach((change) => {
      const objectIndex = change.rowId;
      const fieldName = change.columnId;
      console.log(objectIndex, fieldName, changes, prevObjects);
      const type = change.type;
      switch (type) {
        case "text":
            prevObjects[objectIndex][fieldName] = change.newCell.text;
            break;
        case "number":
            prevObjects[objectIndex][fieldName] = change.newCell.value;
            break;
        case "date":
            change.newCell.date.setDate(change.newCell.date.getDate()+1);
            prevObjects[objectIndex][fieldName] = change.newCell.date;
            break;
        default:
            break;
      }
    });
    return [...prevObjects];
};
const handleChanges = (changes: CellChange[]) => {
        setObje((prevObjects) => applyChangesToObjects(changes, prevObjects));
};
```

El problema es que tengo un ejercicio de práctica en el que uso la librería siguiendo las instrucciones de la página pero consultando los mismos datos que trato de usar en el proyecto completo con ese type y hago la consulta con axios.

```
export type ObjOrdAdm = {
    no: string;
    INDEX: number;
    ID: string;
    _id: string;
    item: string;
    partNo: string;
    descripcion: string;
    matCod: string;
    cantidad: string;
    unitPrice: string;
    valor: string;
    entregado: string;
    folioFactura: string;
    estado: string;
    detalle1: string;
    detalle2: string;
    detalle3: string;
    detalle4: string;
    detalle5: string;
    detalle6: string;
};
const getColumns = (): Column[] => [
    { columnId: 'item', width: 50},
    { columnId: 'partNo', width: 100 },
    { columnId: 'descripcion', width: 310 },
    { columnId: "unitPrice", width: 120 },
    { columnId: "cantidad", width: 100 },
    { columnId: "valor", width: 100 }
];

const headerRow: Row = {
    rowId: "header",
    cells: [
        { type: "header", text: "Item"},
        { type: "header", text: "PartNo" },
        { type: "header", text: "Descipción" },
        { type: "header", text: "Precio unitario" },
        { type: "header", text: "Cantidad" },
        { type: "header", text: "Total" }
    ]
};

const getRows = (objects: ObjOrdAdm[]): Row[] => [
    headerRow,
    ...objects.map<Row>((object) => ({
        rowId: (parseInt(object.item)-1).toString(),
        cells: [
            { type: "text", text: object.item},
            { type: "text", text: object.partNo },
            { type: "text", text: object.descripcion },
            { type: "text", text: object.unitPrice },
            { type: "text", text: object.cantidad },
            { type: "text", text: object.valor }
        ]
      }))
];
const [deezn, setDeezn] = React.useState([] as ObjOrdAdm[]);
```

El ejemplo aislado venido del tutorial funciona bien, pero en el proyecto que estoy haciendo muestra la información pero explota al momento del cambio mostrando el error de type. Las diferencias entre el ejemplo del tutorial y el proyecto son que en el caso aislado le paso todos los datos sacados de la consulta mientras que en mi proyecto hago la consulta, creo un arreglo filtrado con un push y luego el hook de estado y que exporto el type de ObjOrdAdm desde un archivo diferente.
¿Qué puedo hacer para que la tabla de excel funcione también en mi proyecto?

Comment: ¿Porque generic Row aquí `...objects.map<Row>`?

Comment: La verdad ese es el código que genera las rows de la tabla tipo excel proveniente de la documentación de la página, aun tengo problemas para entenderlo

Comment: Bien, dime tienes algún code sandbox o repo para depurar a detalle? saludos

Comment: Desafortunadamente no, es un proyecto para una empresa y solo lo tengo almacenado de forma local

Answer (score 0):

No pude dar muchos detalles pero acabo de darme cuenta de cual es la causa del fallo.
En ambos proyectos uso la misma estructura del type para crear el objeto, pero a la hora de definirlo en el proyecto grande uso el *useDispatch()* y *useSelector* proveniente de react-redux.
Aun soy nuevo en react y no se exactamente porque, pero cuando no uso *useDispatch()* puedo otorgarles valores a las propiedades por separadas de los objetos, pero al usarlo al cambiar un objeto debo definir todas sus propiedades.

```
export const readObjordadm = (): AppThunk => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try{
            const objoa = await axios.get(`${URL}`)
            dispatch(setObjtordadm(objoa.data));
        }catch(error){
            console.log('error', error);
        }
    }
}
```

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const obordadm = useSelector(SelectObjordadm);
const obtOrderadmins = () =>{
        dispatch(readObjordadm());
    };
useEffect(()=>{
        obtOrderadmins();
}, [])
```

Gracias a los que leyeron mi pregunta